# Is is possible to analyze method level dependencies in IntelliJ Idea Ultimate?

Tags: intellij-idea, analysis, intellij-plugin

Is it possible to analyze method-level dependencies in IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2022?

I want to analyze how methods in a class relate to each other. I am seeking functionality like the DSM matrix, as per the Code -> Analyze Code -> Dependency Matrix tool, but with the entries being methods in a selected class. Here is a screenshot of a module-level view:

[image]

What I want is something similar that has methods as rows. Is there a way I can facilitate this type of analysis in IntelliJ Idea 2022?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the Method Call Hierarchy tool that seems to party cover your case: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-structure-and-hierarchy-of-the-source-code.html